# How to cite this booklet/manual?

Tags: citations, bibtex

I am not sure how should I cite this concrete thing - 
https://www.credit-suisse.com/media/assets/corporate/docs/news-and-expertise/articles/2016/07/global-investor-2-15-en.pdf

I am using bibtex, but could not figure out type nor fields in it.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the standard [article entry type](https://www.andy-roberts.net/res/writing/latex/bibentries.pdf)?

> An article from a journal or magazine. Required fields: author, title, journal, year. Optional fields: volume, number, pages, month, note.

Seems like a magazine with articles from different authors to me. If you would want to cite from one of the articles in the magazine, e.g. the first one, it could simply be:

```
@article{Farronato2015,
 author = {Farronato, C. and Levin, J.},
 journal = {Global Investor},
 number = {2},
 pages = {06--13},
 title = {{The rise of peer-to-peer businesses}},
 volume = {15},
 year = {2015}
}
```

Please make sure the citation info is correct before using it though. Quick googling seems to report more than one magazine called 'Global Investor'. Please note that I am also not familiar with this field at all.